# How to override android default ringtone by own customize ringtone using broadcast receiver during incoming call?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to make an application where my purpose is to override the default ringtone and caller screen during the call for a particular contact using broadcast receiver. I already did the caller screen override part. But not able to override the default device ringtone by using broadcast receiver. The requirement is to stop default ringtone during the incoming call and play the sound file which I selected earlier.